# How to properly handle errors raising from get_bucket() function when trying to access a file in GCP Storage?

Tags: python, error-handling, google-cloud-storage

**GOAL**

I want to access and modify a file in a GCP Storage bucket using python.

I implemented this code:

```py
def get_file_from_bucket(file_name, bucket_name):
    # get storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    # get bucket with name
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    # get bucket data as blob
    blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)
    # convert to text
    text = blob.download_as_text()

    return text
```

It is working fine. I get access to the file.

**PROBLEM**

If the bucket gets somehow deleted in GCP Storage, my code will raise an error when trying to access it:

- `google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET {link_to_my_file}: The specified bucket does not exist.` will be raised when the bucket doesn't exist.

I know I need to catch the errors with an `try except` but I also know that a bare except is not a good practice and since I am not able to find any details about the errors that may be raised, I don't know how to do it.

```py
try:
    # get bucket with name
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
except Exception:    ----> what kind of exception should I place here ?
    do_stuff()
```

**QUESTION**

How can I handle errors when trying to access a file in GCP Storage using Python ?

What kind of errors should I expect ? How many are they ?

Bonus question : Where can I find accurate documentation about this ? [This](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/errors) seems to be obsolete

Comment: Your question is too broad. Ask one well-defined question per post. 1) Your link is for App Engine and not for the Python SDK. 2) To determine the exceptions, consult the API documentation. Look for the entry **raises**. This will tell you the exception(s) that the method might generate. For example **download_as_text()** internally calls **download_as_bytes()** which can raise **google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound**. https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html

Comment: Sometimes you must look at the source code: https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.download_as_bytes

Comment: @JohnHanley I couldn't find any hints in the docs about the function `get_bucket`  which is the main problem here. There is a lot of examples using this function but none of them are handling a possible error coming from it. They all assume the existence of the file in the bucket. I cannot assume that.

Comment: Review the source file that I linked to in my comment, notice the import **from google.cloud import exceptions**. That import which is a file will contain the Google-specific exceptions that the Python SDK can generate. Link: https://gcloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/cloud/exceptions.html The secret is to not rely on documentation. Spend time understanding the SDK and then you will know how to look up which exceptions can be generated.

Comment: Also important is to understand the REST API. This link shows the possible errors. Each error results in an equivalent exception: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the docs: https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.get_bucket

The code:

```py
try:
    bucket = client.get_bucket("my-bucket")
except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
    print("Sorry, that bucket does not exist!")
```